# Entity Framework: No accessible 'where' can be called without narrowing conversion?

Tags: .net, vb.net, entity-framework

Here is my function:

```
Public Function ListPublishedArticles(ByVal startingDate As DateTime) As List(Of Article)
        Dim db As ArticleEntities = ArticleEntitiesFactory.Current()
        Dim listArticles As List(Of Article) = Nothing

        If startingDate <> Nothing Then
            listArticles = db.Articles.Where(Function(x) x.Publish = True And x.startTime <= startingDate)
        End If

        Return listArticles
    End Function
```

On the .Where() I get the following error:

```
No Accessible 'where' can be called without narrowing conversion. Candidates are
   Public Function Where(Of Article)(IEnumerable(Of Article), Func(Of Article, Boolean)) As IEnumerable(Of Article) (In Class Enumerable)
   Public Function Where(Of Article)(IQueryable(Of Article), Expression(Of Func(Article, Boolean))) As IQueryable(Of Article) (In Class Queryable)
```

I understand the error but am not sure how to fix it, how do I tell it which one I am using? On msdn it says to ignore this error turn Option Strict to Off, but it is already off. It's not showing up as an error in the error list at the bottom, just a red underline, but it is preventing me from continuing with .OrderBy() and anymore functions.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well it seems like the answer was obvious and I just wasn't getting, all I needed to do was CType the Where expression to either one of the types of the parameters like so:

```
.Where(Ctype(Function(x) x.Publish = True And x.startTime <= startingDate, Func(Of Article, Boolean)))
```

Answer (score 2):

I realise this post is pretty old but I recently encountered the same issue which turned out to be because I was evaluating a boolean? = True. I avoided casting the whole expression by calling .Equals() extension method on my boolean? parameter i.e.

```
.Where(Function(x) x.Publish.Equals(True) And x.startTime <= startingDate)
```

alternatively

```
.Where(Function(x) (x.Publish.HasValue AndAlso x.Publish.Value = True) And x.startTime <= startingDate)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try calling `ToList()`. This will get it to `List(Of Article)`

Comment: Can't do that either, anything I put after it says "Cannot Resolve Symbol (x)). It's not erroring because I am trying to convert the result into a list without calling ToList(). It's saying it doesn't know which overloaded where method to use on the query, but I don't know how to tell it which one. I've never had this problem before because typically I only use queries inside a Using block in the past, but I just revised my framework to handle the data context in a new way and now this pops up.